# Помогите разобраться в символах регулярного выражения в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Объясните новичку каждый символ этого, регулярного выражения

```
( '~\\b([a-zа-яё]{' . $maxValue. '})[a-zа-яё]+\\b~iu')
```

я что лучше, понять что здесь происходить.

И второй вопрос: что надо добавить в код, чтобы получилось такое слово: `я летел  на вертол* вчера...`
Вот код программы:

```
$maxValue = 6;
$Mytext = "я летел  на вертолете вчера";
echo preg_replace('~\\b([a-zа-яё]{' . $maxValue. '})[a-zа-яё]+\\b~iu', '$1*', $Mytext);
```

Comment: Вы читали хоть немного о регулярных выражениях ? если да, то не может быть, что Вам все непонятно.

Comment: Мне много чего здесь не понятно, скажу честно я пока просто учусь.

Comment: См. https://regex101.com/r/EedLZF/2

Comment: напишите, что конкретно Вам непонятно. Чтобы научиться, Вам необходимо вначале самому попытаться разобраться с вопросом

Comment: если уже regex101, то [так](https://regex101.com/r/fwDebW/2) , в регулярном выражении вероятно ошибка и нужно не `\\b`, а `\b`

Comment: мне нужно что в конце слова вывода троеточие

Comment: так уж тогда https://regex101.com/r/fwDebW/3  c заменой.

Comment: а многоточие в конце это `/$/` на `...` просто. preg_replace может принимать первыми параметрами массивы. шаблоны и замены.  вот из этих двух шабонов и замен сделайте массив

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Объясните новичку каждый символ этого, регулярного выражения

```
echo preg_replace('~\\b([a-zа-яё]{' . $maxValue. '})[a-zа-яё]+\\b~iu', '$1*',  $Mytext);
```

Если в ваше выражение подставить значение `maxValue` и убрать лишние слэши, то само выражение будет таким:

```
~\b([a-zа-яё]{6})[a-zа-яё]+\b~iu
```

происходит тут следующее:

- `~` ограничивают само выражение (чаще используют `/`)
- `iu` модификаторы регистронезависимого (`i`) и юникод `u` поиска
- `[a-zа-яё]` обозначает набор (диапазон) символов, которые ищем.
- `{6}` данному диапазону удовлетворяют 6 символов подряд
- `(...)`, это т.н. *группа захвата*, то есть эти 6 символов мы будем искать и извлекать (захватывать).
- после группы у нас опять идет подобный дипазон со знаком `+`, который обозначает 1 и более вхождений. В итоге получаем 6 в группе, и еще сколько то, но больше одного. То есть 7 и более.
- `\b` это граница слова. Пробелы, запятые, конец строки и т.п.
- заменяется на `$1*`, где `$1` это первая группа захвата (нулевая это вся строка), а `*` это ваша звездочка.

Чтобы в конец добавить `...` надо `$` (обозначение конца строки) заменить на это самое многоточие.
`preg_replace` может принимать массив шаблонов и замен. Так что все вместе будет

```
    echo preg_replace(
                [ '~\b([a-zа-яё]{' . $maxValue. '})[a-zа-яё]+\b~iu', '/$/' ],
                ['$1*', '...'],
            $Mytext);
```